# Using Captcha with Symfony2 (2.8)

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, captcha, symfony-2.8

I installed Captcha bundle using this following [Instruction](https://github.com/Gregwar/CaptchaBundle/tree/2.0):

1. Add `"gregwar/captcha-bundle": "1.0.0"` to `require` section in `composer.json`
2. Run `Windows PowerShell` in root and call `php composer.phar update`
3. Console outputs

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_yaml.dll' - Nie mo┐na odnalečŠ okreťlonego
>   modu│u. in Unknown on line 0 Loading composer repositories with
>   package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Nothing to install or update Generating autoload files
>   Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters Updating the
>   "app/config/parameters.yml" file
>   Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_yaml.dll' - Nie mo┐na odnalečŠ okreťlonego
>   modu│u.  in Unknown on line 0
>   Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_yaml.dll' - Nie mo┐na odnalečŠ okreťlonego
>   modu│u.  in Unknown on line 0
>
> // Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true
>
> [OK] Cache for the "dev" environment (debug=true) was successfully
>   cleared.
>
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installAssets
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_yaml.dll' - Nie mo┐na odnalečŠ okreťlonego
>   modu│u.  in Unknown on line 0
>
> Trying to install assets as relative symbolic links.
>
> ```
>         Bundle                 Method / Error
> ```
>
> WARNING   FrameworkBundle        copy
>   WARNING   JMSTranslationBundle   copy
>
> ! [NOTE] Some assets were installed via copy. If you make changes to
>   these assets you have to run this command again.
>
> [OK] All assets were successfully installed.
>
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile
>   Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget

4. Following instruction I can skip this step

   ```
   // app/autoload.php

   $loader->registerNamspaces(array(
       // ...
       'Gregwar' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
   ));
   ```

but my autoload.php files looks following:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;

error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);

$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

return $loader;
```

5. I enabled bundle:

   ```
   // app/appKernel.php

   public function registerBundles()
   {
       $bundles = array(
           // ...
           new Gregwar\CaptchaBundle\GregwarCaptchaBundle(),
       );
   }
   ```
6. Last instalation step is add `gregwar_captcha: ~` to `app/config/config.yml` and it's done.

Now I'm trying to use it im my controller.

```
    public function registrationAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new Models\User();

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
            ->add('username', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType')
            ->add('birth', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType')
            ->add('captcha', 'captcha')
            ->add('save', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType', array('label' => 'Register'))
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);



        return $this->render(
             'CassyW2Bundle:User:registration.html.twig',
             array(
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            )
        );
    }
```

I get error:

```
Compile Error: Declaration of Gregwar\CaptchaBundle\Type\CaptchaType::buildView() must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface::buildView(Symfony\Component\Form\FormView $view, Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface $form, array $options)
```

Where did I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Doc](https://github.com/Gregwar/CaptchaBundle/tree/master). For your version of symfony you need another version of this bundle. Try installing it without providing version in `composer.json`.

Comment: I change version to 2.0.0 and run composer update. It downloads v1.1.1 but it works ;-)

Comment: As I see, you don't even need to provide any version - in this case (as I understand) latest commit from master will be cloned.

Answer (score 0):

According to the warning, try to install the php_yaml extension by downloading this from the PEAR's sitweb https://pecl.php.net/package/yaml.

Choose the stable version and copy the dll when extracted to **C:\xampp\php\ext**

Comment: Thanks :-) Trust me, I've try all possible version of this dll files. This warning displays everytime when I call `php` in console but YAML works properly. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/UPGRADE-2.1.md#form

If you check Upgrade docs which version related Symfony 2.1 FormTypeInterface changed and it is a BC break which used in
https://github.com/Gregwar/CaptchaBundle/blob/v1.0.0/Type/CaptchaType.php

So Symfony 2.8 is not compatible with this bundle version 1.0.0 There is version 2.0 tagged, please use this and if there is still problem open another question.